# Single_cat_title() print the title before text

Tags: categories, themes, title

When I use **single_cat_title()** get the name of the current category in archive page, it works perfectly but it prints the category title before the text

```
<h2>
    <?php 
        if (is_category()){
            echo 'Category: ' . single_cat_title();
        }
    ?>
</h2>
```

It says:

> UncategorizedCategory:

How do I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `display` argument of the function to `false`.

```
<h2>
    <?php 
        if (is_category()){
            echo 'Category: ' . single_cat_title( '', false);
        }
    ?>
</h2>
```

Or, to use the function in its more "helpful" form you could do:

```
single_cat_title('Category: ');
```

If the display argument is true, WordPress automatically echoes the content on to the page usually within a wrapper html element and this messes with your `echo`.